# Is it possible to set a scope for a block that will apply to child relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

scoping does not apply to child scopes.  ie:

```
Book.where(title: some_title).scoping { some_library.books.first }
```

Does not do what I would hope.  Is there a way to set a scope and have it apply to child scopes inside the block?

Answer (score 1):

The following code could be helpful.

```
class Library < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books

  scope :is_e, { where(electronic: true) }
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :library

  scope :with_title, -> (value) { where(title: value) }
  scope :in_e_library, -> { joins(:library).merge(Library.is_e) }
end

Book.with_title(some_title).in_e_library
```

Comment: I would have done that `Book.joins(:library).merge(Library.is_e)`.  Unless I did it a lot - in which case I might have done what you did.

But that's not what I want.  I want to set a scope and apply it to a block and have it also apply to child relationships.